# sql insert 2 select

Tags: sql

Как в sql через insert вставить 2 select?
Например:

```
create table #TNK(мфк nvarchar(255),  Lastweek nvarchar(255), Thisweek nvarchar (255))

insert into #TNK(Категория, Thisweek)
(SELECT distinct
  запросы.КАТЕГОРИЯ
  ,запросы.СОК
FROM
  запросы
inner join сотрудники on запросы.ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ=сотрудники.КОД_СОТРУДНИКА
WHERE
  AND запросы.ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ_ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ >= @time1
  AND запросы.ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ_ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ <= @time2
  AND запросы.КАТЕГОРИЯ LIKE N'запрос')

insert into #TNK(Категория, Lastweek)
(SELECT distinct
  запросы.КАТЕГОРИЯ
  ,запросы.СОК
FROM
  запросы
inner join сотрудники on запросы.ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ=сотрудники.КОД_СОТРУДНИКА
WHERE
  AND запросы.ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ_ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ >= @pretime1
  AND запросы.ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ_ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ <= @pretime2
  AND запросы.КАТЕГОРИЯ LIKE N'запрос')
```

Comment: Делайте две выборки и join по PK таблицы `запросы`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

UNION:

```
    insert into #TNK(Категория, Lastweek, Thisweek)
    (SELECT distinct
      запросы.КАТЕГОРИЯ
      ,NULL         --Lastweek
      ,запросы.СОК  --Thisweek
    FROM
      запросы
    inner join сотрудники on запросы.ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ=сотрудники.КОД_СОТРУДНИКА
    WHERE
      AND запросы.ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ_ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ >= @time1
      AND запросы.ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ_ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ <= @time2
      AND запросы.КАТЕГОРИЯ LIKE N'запрос'

    UNION

    SELECT distinct
       запросы.КАТЕГОРИЯ
      ,запросы.СОК     --Lastweek
      ,NULL            --Thisweek
    FROM
      запросы
    inner join сотрудники on запросы.ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ=сотрудники.КОД_СОТРУДНИКА
    WHERE
      AND запросы.ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ_ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ >= @pretime1
      AND запросы.ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ_ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ <= @pretime2
      AND запросы.КАТЕГОРИЯ LIKE N'запрос')
```

Но запрос некорректный. Таблица `сотрудники` нигде не используется, но она есть в `inner join` - лишняя.

Comment: `inner join сотрудники` - если нет сотрудника, то вставки строки не будет, а значит некоторый смысл в этом все-таки есть. Улучшить, конечно, можно, но не зная используемой логики трудно сказать как лучше сделать. Например, если сотрудники удаляются безвозвратно, то было бы логично обнулять `ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ` и тогда выборка была бы по `WHERE ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ IS NOT NULL`. Если удаленные сотрудники переносятся в другую таблицу, тогда можно было бы переносить и связанные с ними запросы в другую таблицу, либо выставлять таким запросам флаг "неназначены" и т.д.

Comment: запрос не полный, в остальной части применяется "сотрудники". А за ответ спасибо, я не подумал, что можно NULL поставить в значения